# Visual Studio Code Sidebars and Tabs is Suddenly Purple Theme now

Tags: visual-studio-code

The sidebars are suddenly purple color theme now.

I don't know, I changed no settings. Tried to set it to black again but they are still this color. Tried uninstalling different theme extension but to no avail.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the "Preferences: Color Theme" menu by selecting "File" > "Preferences" > "Color Theme".

Select a different color theme from the list and see if the sidebars and tabs return to the expected color.

If it does not work, try resetting the color theme to the default settings. Go to the "Preferences: Open User Settings" menu by selecting "File" > "Preferences" > "Settings".

In the "Settings" window, search for "workbench.colorTheme" and click the "Edit in settings.json" link.

In the "settings.json" file, delete any entries under "workbench.colorTheme" and save the file. This should reset the color theme to the default settings.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by deleting everything from "workbench.colorCustomizations" in settings.json